# Decompose a Hilbert space into two invariant subspaces

Tags: oa.operator-algebras

[image]The following conclusion is from Bourin, Lee, Pinchings and positive linear maps [arXiv:1505.02341 [math.FA]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.02341) [zbMath](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1345.46050)

Let $Q$ be an idempotent in $L(H)$.Then we have a decomposition $H=H_s\oplus H_{ns}$ in two invatiant subspaces of $Q$ such that $Q$ acts on $H_s$ as a self-adjoint projection $P$, and $Q$ acts on $H_{ns}$ as a purely non-self-adjoint idempotent , that is $Q_{H_{ns}}$ is unitarily equivalent to an operator on $F\oplus F$ of the form $ 
  Q_{H_{ns}}\cong\begin{pmatrix}I & 0\\R& 0\end{pmatrix}$.

My question : how to construct $H_s$ and $H_{ns}$?. It is natrual to think of the following decomposition :$H=QH\oplus (I-Q)H$, but $Q|_{QH}$ is not a projection.

Comment: Could you give the title, and a link, to the paper?

Comment: The title is "Pinchings and positive linear maps" and the above conclusion is from the proof of Proposition 2.8

Comment: @MatthewDaws, I have added the screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the zbMath review of the paper the OP asks about, there is mention of "idempotents" and a link to this paper: Loreaux, Weiss, Diagonality and idempotents with applications to problems in operator theory and frame theory   [arXiv:1410.7441 [math.FA]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.7441) [zbMath](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A6658771)

Remark 2.3 in this paper of Loreaux and Weiss exactly answers the OP's question.

Comment: Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

Let $H_2=N(Q)$, $H_1=N(Q)^{\perp}$. If $x\in H_1$, then $Qx=x+(Qx-x)$ is the representation of $Qx$ with respect to this decomposition $H=H_1\oplus H_2$, since $Q(Qx-x)=0$.

In other words,
$$
Q= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ R & 0 \end{pmatrix} ,
$$
as desired.

What is a bit strange about this is that a projection can be self-adjoint and at the same time purely non-self-adjoint if your definition is taken literally (when $R=0$). I suspect that in the original statement, we further split off $N(R)$ from $H_1$, and then we can also shuffle subspaces of $H_2$ around between the two summands.

Comment: What is $N(Q)$? Is $N(Q)=\{x\in H: Qx=0\}$?

Comment: Yes.   ----------------

Comment: But in the above conclusion $Q$ is unitarily equivalent to the matrix.